# How can I show that $A^{-} A=I_{n} \text { if and only if } \operatorname{rank}(A)=n$?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-rank

$A^{-}$ means minus inverse of matrix A.

How can I show that $A^{-}A=I_{n} \text { if and only if } \operatorname{rank}(A)=n$?

I don't know how to start with it, or it's there exist some great theorems can help me figure it out at once.

Any suggestions or hints? Please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Presumably you've tried separating it into two one-directional claims, i.e. "If $A^{-1}A=I_n$, then rank$(A)=n$", and vice versa. In the second direction I listed, it seems to follow fairly straightforwardly by contradiction. (Perhaps contradiction works in the first case as well: if the LHS is true, can rank$(A)\neq n$?

Comment: I see that you type the $A^{-1}$, I think $ A^{-} \neq A^{-1} $..Right? This is the concept of generalized inverse.

Comment: I know what the inverse of a matrix is, but what is the minus inverse of a matrix?

Comment: Let $A \in R^{m \times n}$, if there exists a $G \in R^{n \times m}$ such
that for any $b \in R(A), G b$ is a solution to $A x=b$, then $G$ is
called a minus inverse of $A,$ denoted by $A^{-} .$

Comment: One implication has nothing to do with generalised inverses: $BA=I_n$ implies $BA$ is $1-1$ implies $A$ is $1-1$, so $A$ has rank $n$. And if the rank of $A$ is $n$ surely it's easy to construct a minus inverse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$A^-$ is the generalized inverse of $A$ $$$$Suppose that $A\in\mathbb{F}^{m\times n}$ then $\exists P\in GL_m(\mathbb{F})$ $Q\in GL_n(\mathbb{F})$ s.t. $A=P\begin{bmatrix} I_r&O\\O&O\end{bmatrix}Q$, where $r=\text{rank}(A)$. $A^-=Q^{-1}\begin{bmatrix} I_r&B\\C&D\end{bmatrix}P^{-1}$ for all matrices $B$,$C$,$D$.$$$$
Since rank$(MN)\leq $rank$(M)$, and rank$(MN)\leq $rank$(N)$, it is obvious that $A^{-}A=I_{n} \text { is always correct if and only if } \operatorname{rank}(A)=n$

Comment: Inspired by you. I find a theorem that "Let $A \in R^{m \times n} $ with $rank(A)=r$, if there exist nonsingular matrices P, Q such that $P A Q=\left(\begin{array}{cc}{l_{r}} & {0} \\ {0} & {0}\end{array}\right)$ then $G (A^{-})\in A\{1\} $ if and only if $G=Q\left(\begin{array}{ll}{l_{r}} & {K} \\ {L} & {M}\end{array}\right) P$. K,L,M arbitrary" I think It shows obviously that $rank(A)=n$.